# Xamarin android image URI to Byte array

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

i'm simply trying to upload image to server.

when i choose image from , i get URI to that image.
the question is how can i convert this URI to `byte[]` byte array?

no more no less. thats my question

this is what ive been trying.

i tried to rewrite this https://colinyeoh.wordpress.com/2012/05/18/android-convert-image-uri-to-byte-array/
to C#

```
    public byte[] convertImageToByte(Android.Net.Uri uri)
    {
        byte[] data = null;
        try
        {

            ContentResolver cr = this.ContentResolver;
            var inputStream = cr.OpenInputStream(uri);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(inputStream);
            var baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, baos);
            data = baos.ToByteArray();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.PrintStackTrace();
        }
        return data;
    }
```

but the error...

```
Error CS1503: Argument `#3' cannot convert `Java.IO.ByteArrayOutputStream' expression to type `System.IO.Stream' (CS1503) (Foodle.Droid)
```

how to fix this? or new code to get image from gallery and convert that to byte array is fine.

help!

Comment: You could try reading all the data using inputStream.Read(), then using  BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); to get the image

Answer (score 7):

```
public byte[] convertImageToByte(Android.Net.Uri uri)
{
    Stream stream = ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(uri);   
    byte[] byteArray;

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
       stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
       byteArray = memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
    return byteArray;
}
```

Comment: what here is to explain? User want's to take byteArray from android image object (Android.Net.Uri) and this method is doing the job.

Comment: p.s. eventualy, you can use DI and return Stream stream from android code, and use MemoryStream in shared code.

Comment: what is this fileStream?

Comment: this fileStream is just stream